# Redundancy in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have started to learn Lisp and was wondering if all the redundancies of doing a particular task in several different ways useful? Am sure experienced Lisp programmers can answer this question.

To just quote an example. We can create functions by following 2 different ways.

```
(defun add2 (x) (+ x 2))
```

or

```
(setf (symbol-function 'add2)
  #'(lambda (x) (+ x 2))
```

I understand that this provides flexibility to achieve different things. But a proper explanation as to why have all this redundancy can help me understand things better.

Answer (score 15):

The first form exists because defining functions is such a common chore that you want a convenient syntax for it.

The second form exists because sometimes, you want to do advanced things with macros generating function definitions and whatnot.

If there had been no `defun`, we could still define functions with your second form, but nobody would be programming in Lisp because a simple task would be extremely arduous. Every programmer would be designing their own `defun` macro, incompatible with all the others.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at DEFUN in existing implementations, it does much more than just defining a function. It records for example the definition location for the IDE (development environment), sets the documentation, records the type information, ...

Often Lisp exposes a machinery in terms of a functional interface. The typical usage is then done via a set of macros which provide a convenient interface and side effects in the development environment.

Sometimes, with CLOS, there is even an object-oriented implementation underneath the functional interface.

The picture then looks like this

```
macros <- used by the programmer, convenient to use
   ^
   |
functions <- user interface to the implementation
   ^
   |
CLOS (classes, instances, generic functions) <- low-level extensible machine
```

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is basically a side-effect of the fact that a large part of Lisp is written in itself. So both the high-level definitions meant to be used usually, and the low-level stuff behind it is available to the programmer.

Having the low-level definitions available can be very nice if you want to do advanced stuff that would otherwise not be possible, but usually it can be treated as an implementation detail.